# memory trouble with doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a doubly linked list. The following code passes my tests, but I'm allocating memory for new nodes in both the `next` direction and the `prev` direction. Specifically, the problem is that I believe I shouldn't have to allocate `current` in the `push` function because those nodes were already allocated in past iterations with `new`. However, **if I set `new->prev = current` without allocating `current` I get a segmentation fault**. Note that the code below functions properly as a singly linked list if I don't allocate the `current` or use `->prev`.

After removing the malloc for current, the code segfaults after printing testing (on the first use of `prev`).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct list{
    int value;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *prev;
};
struct list *head;
struct list *tail;

void init(int val){
    head = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list *));
    head->value = val;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->prev = NULL;

    tail = malloc(sizeof(struct list *)); 
    tail->value = val;
    tail->next = NULL;
    tail->prev = NULL;

}

void push(int val){
     struct list *new;
     struct list *current;
     new = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list *)); //allocate memory space for next side
     current = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list *)); //allocate memory space for prev side
     new->value = val;
     new->next = NULL;
     current = head;
     while(current->next!=NULL){current = current->next;}
     new->prev = current;
     current->next = new;
     tail = new;
 }

 int main(){
     printf("init with 10\n");
     init(10);
     printf("pushing 11\n");
     push(11);
     printf("pushing 12\n");
     push(12);
     printf("pushing 13\n");
     push(13);
     printf("testing\n");
     printf("2-1 %d\n",head->next->prev->value);
     printf("3-1 %d\n",head->next->next->prev->value);
     printf("h4-1 %d\n",head->next->next->next->prev->value);
     printf("t-1 %d\n",tail->prev->value);
     printf("t-2 %d\n",tail->prev->prev->value);
     printf("t %d\n",tail->value);
 }
```

Comment: Why doesn't `init()` initialize `tail->prev = NULL;`?  IMO, `tail` and `head` should get the same value here.  NO need for 2 calls to `malloc()`.  Leave to others to answer.

Comment: Why do you allocate space for two nodes when you only want to push one?

Comment: If you don't allocate current (which you should not be doing), where is the seg fault?

Comment: `init` should declare the type of `val`, and allocate only the head node, and set `tail = head`.  `push` should not allocate a node for `current`, and you don't need to traverse the list to find the end, because `tail` points at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious error is you are allocating memory in pointer size bits, not the size of the list node. Try and change your `mallocs` to:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct list));  // note the missing '*'
```

I bet that will fix most of your memory problems in one swoop. Not all though, for instance you still have a memory leak by overwriting current after allocating it (even though, as other posters say, it's not necessary)

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my comment above:

```
void init(int val){
    head = malloc(sizeof *head);
    head->value = val;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->prev = NULL;
    tail = head;
}

void push(int val){
     struct list *new;
     new = malloc(sizeof *new); //allocate memory space for next side
     new->value = val;
     new->next = NULL;
     new->prev = tail;
     tail->next = new;
     tail = new;
 }
```

You should also make sure that `malloc` doesn't return `NULL`, but error handling messes everything up!

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't allocate a new list (here `current`) every push; just make it point on `head`. Here you are just allocating a list and right after make the pointer to this list pointing to your `head`. So there's no point to alloc it.

An allocation create enough space writtable by your programme, the pointer only store the address and that is what you want cause your pointer on the address  won't change as long as you iterate your `current` instead of `head`.

I could have lost myself in those explaination and maybe lost the purpose of your question but hope this will help you.

Oh and one last thing, maybe you should make `tail->prev` point on `head`.

But there's I still don't understand why you allocate 2 node in your init instead of pushing them 1 by 1 to your head